# Fixed, full-height sidebar (of variable width/position)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is Javascript the only way to achieve a full-height sidebar of variable width/position (where the main content responds by adjusting its own width)?

What I have been working to achieve is to have a fixed, full-height sidebar slide in from the side and have the main content to its right respond by adjusting its width. I hope to achieve this using only css and no js or percentage widths.

I know that I can achieve a fixed sidebar of variable width, but it requires js to adjust the margin property of the main content area. Ideally, I can use the sidebar's x-position to show/hide and the main content, being beside it, automatically adjusts.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

> **Current css-only implementation does not support full height**

```
<!--HTML-->
<div id="container">
   <div id="sidebar">sidebar, hidden with negative margin</div><!-- end sidebar -->
   <div id="content">main content</div><!-- end content -->
</div><!-- end container -->


<!--CSS pseudo-code-->
#container {
   position:relative;
}
#sidebar {
   float:left;
   width:300px;
}
#content {}
```

> **Implementation requiring javascript**

```
<!--HTML-->
<div id="container">
   <div id="sidebar">sidebar, hidden with width or position</div><!-- end sidebar -->
   <div id="content">main content, margin-left adjusted using js</div><!-- end content -->
</div><!-- end container -->


<!--CSS pseudo-code-->
#container {
   position:relative;
}
#sidebar {
   width:300px;
}
#content {
   margin-left: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Please post some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a 2 column layout with both of them expanding to match the height of the sidebar or the main content, you should use the [Maxdesign layouts](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/) and modify them.